# Connect to external SQL Server through Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-connection, connection-string

Basically I need to test a database on an external server (the model matches the model of my local test database).

Here is the connection string I have so far:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" 
        connectionString="Database=QualityLinkBuilder;Server=12.345.678.901.\SQLExpress;uid=RemotePc\Administrator;pwd=MyPassword;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I attempt to connect now I get the generic error:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

Inner exception message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Answer (score 0):

It should be just `Server=12.345.678.901\SQLExpress` in your connection string ( replace "\SQLExpress" with the relevant SQL Server instance name on the external server )

Comment: I've updated my connection string as per your suggestion (as shown in the question) but I still get the very same error.

Comment: Can you connect to the database outside of Entity Framework - through SQL Server Management Studio ?

Comment: As a matter of fact I can't. I get the same error as EF throws.

Comment: Then that is the problem - nothing to do with your EF connection.